# Property 'toDate' does not exist on type 'FieldValue | Timestamp' but WORKS

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm using Cloud Firestore to store Chats, which I would like to sort by lastestMessage.created. I was not able to use the query because I was using it for something else so I'm using the SORT function to do it.

I keep getting this error on VS Code:

Property 'toDate' does not exist on type 'FieldValue | Timestamp'.

However, the code runs just fine, it compares it and returns it correctly. With no errors in the console.

```
      chats.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (b.latestMessage.created && a.latestMessage.created) {
          return b.latestMessage.created.toDate() - a.latestMessage.created.toDate();
        }
      });


(parameter) a: {
    contractId?: string;
    members: any;
    contact: any;
    latestMessage?: Message;
    id?: string;
    created?: firebase.firestore.FieldValue | firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
    modified?: firebase.firestore.FieldValue | firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
}
```

It's just annoying that this false ERROR keeps showing when I compile and that it works perfectly...

Comment: Could you edit the quesiton to show the type definition of whatever `a` and `b` are in this case?

Comment: Did you try to cast `b.latestMessage.created` and `a.latestMessage.created` to Timestamp type ?

Comment: @DougStevenson done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `created` and `modified` properties are both typed to accept either s FieldValue or Timestamp type object.  It's not clear to me what that's necessary.  Since the compiler doesn't know which one it is, you can only call methods that they have in common, so toDate is not value.

If you want it to be a Timestamp type that you can call toDate, then you will have to either remove FieldValue from the possible type, or cast the value to Timestamp, so the compiler knows exactly what you think you're dealing with.